# SyntaxError: missing } after property list javascript

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

I am getting the below error.

**Error**

> SyntaxError: missing } after property list
>
> content:Al futaim, trading company`<br />`Building M, 36, Saih Shuaib 3
>   —

**PHP code**

```
$content=$servicecenter->getCompanyName()."<br />".$servicecenter->getAddress()."<br /><button type='button' value='Get Direction' class='button' onclick='closeInfoWindow(),calcRoute()' name='Get Direction'>Get Direction</button>";
```

**Script**

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:<?php echo $content; ?>;
});
```

Comment: You need to add the quotes (either doulbe or single quotes will do)

Comment: To add some more info: You need to add the quotes (either double or single quotes will do), remove the semicolon after the php closing tag and remember to escape your output (i.e. try addslashes or htmlentities)

Comment: i got error after adding the quotes 
 
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal content:

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `json_encode` and delete the semicolon at end of line:

```
content: <?php echo json_encode($content); ?>  /* no ; here! */
```

Comment: This is actually the best solution... You don't have to concern yourself with how it is outputted, it will always do it right ;)

Comment: TIL a strikethrough semicolon looks horrible :)

Answer (score 10):

Missing the `quote`s for content and no need of `;` -

```
content: '<?php echo $content; ?>'
```

OR

```
content: <?php echo json_encode($content); ?>
```

Comment: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
 

content:'Al futaim, trading company<br />Building M, 36, Saih Shuaib

Comment: Shouldn't they be double quotes `"` as there's already single quotes in the string?

Comment: getting this error i tried it before but getting these error

Comment: The semicolon is a matter of preference. Some like it, some don't ... Can't argue use... Sorry, you meant in the JavaScript - yes that will break. In the php code it's optional...

Comment: @Svengali Don't you need to escape whatever you output to the browser that's possibly dangerous? :)

Comment: Check the source and the error might be because of `'`/`"` Or escape the content properly.

Comment: Generating a JavaScript string with `json_encode` is safer than manually putting the quotes in.

Comment: stdob--'s answer is better in this case.

Answer (score 3):

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:<?php echo $content; ?>
});
```

You can't have a `;` inside an object's declaration. If you want to separate properties, use `,`.

Also, depending on what you want to echo there, you might need to add `"` around the php script.