# Highcharts and sessionStorage (JS)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to play with highcharts and pass data between a couple of pages depending on what element of a graph is clicked.

I have an array built up (from JIRA) which has all my data - and I use that to create a pie chart.  That all works as expected.
I have added in an events block to the series block of my data

```
          events: {
            click: function () {
                location.href = 'severity_data.php';
            }
          }
```

and that works as expected.

I then set at a high level a simple

```
sessionStorage.setItem("faveFilm", "shrek");
```

and on the PHP page, which at the moment is just a boilerplate html, I added

```
            // var favoriteMovie = sessionStorage.getItem('faveFilm');
            // console.log(favoriteMovie)
```

and saw "shrek" in the console.

I modified the code to send a the JSON and decoded it and saw the data was there.  Everything great so far.

I then tried to use this within highcharts.

My first attempt was to insert a key

```
key: sessionStorage.setItem("severity", sessionStorage.setItem("majorArray", JSON.stringify(major_data)););
```

however, this didn't work as I got some form of {} mismatch (guessing this was to do with the array and it messing up the structure of the highcharts code. (and my thinking was each element of the graph would send a different array)

Then I thought I could take a step backwards, maybe set all the data in session and in the key just send the word for the graph element I clicked:

```
{
    name: 'Major',
    y: majorCount,
    key: sessionStorage.setItem("severity", "Major");
}
```

However, when I run this I get:

***Uncaught SyntaxError: missing } after property listseverity2.php:93:58***

***note: { opened at line 90, column 11***

Line 93 (on generated output) is key: sessionStorage.setItem("severity", "Major");

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your php file should be like this

```php
<?php echo json_encode( php code or variable or function ); ?>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31743698

Comment: No, that doesn't help.  The originating PHP file does have a the json, but where I am setting the sessionStroage is in plain JS - and this is after a filter operation has been done.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can not use a semicolon in an object notation. You need to remove `;` at the end of the key value. However, the below notation:

```
{
    name: 'Major',
    y: majorCount,
    key: sessionStorage.setItem("severity", "Major")
}
```

will of course save the specific value in a session storage, but it will result in:

```
{
    name: 'Major',
    y: majorCount,
    key: undefined
}
```

The same situation with:

```
sessionStorage.setItem(
    "severity", 
    sessionStorage.setItem("majorArray", JSON.stringify(major_data))
);
```

You should use both `setItem` and `getItem` methods and remember that `setItem` will return undefined.

---

**Docs:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage